# Orleans client not able to access Silo hosted on another azure app service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, orleans

I've two separate apps for orleans Client and Silo and both are hosted in different azure app services. My client is an console app so it is hosted via webjobs. Both app services are in same resource group and under one VNet. I've used Azure storage clustering to configure silo.
Here is the error from webjobs console:
*Unable to connect to endpoint S1XX.XX.XX:30000
Orleans.Runtime.Messaging.ConnectionManager..ConnectAsync(SiloAddress Address)*

I see the changes in the azure table after silo initialized and client is also trying to connect to the same silo but it fails.

Comment: Hi Jasmin, this kind of question is well suited for a GitHub issue, since it may require a back-and-forth to troubleshoot. I would like to point you to this issue where Azure App Service on Orleans is discussed: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/7098